# F# - Cast string to <m>?

Tags: f#

Is there anyhow I can cast a normal `string` to `<m>` where `m` is a measure type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like

```
let convert (s:string) : float<m> = 
  float s 
  |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure
```

Comment: I dunno, seems kinda primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides kvb's approach would be to multiply a raw float value by `1.0<m>`:

```
let convert (s:string) =
    (float s) * 1.0<m>
```

Answer (score 2):

To add another alternative, I'd probably write:

```
let inline convertToMeters x : float<m> = unbox (box (float x));;
```

You can use the function to convert any type that can be converted to `float` to the type `float<m>` (which is nice, because it also works with integers etc., but not all random types such as `System.Random`). You can see this from the type signature:

```
val inline convertToMeters :
   ^a -> float<m> when  ^a : (static member op_Explicit :  ^a -> float)
```

Comment: Note that if you want to generalize, you can go even farther and have the result type be `float<'t>` instead of `float<m>`.